# Plotly - Checkbox instead of dropdown selection

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization

I am trying to use plotly to display a Line chart with sliders and a checkbox dropdown for filters.

My DataFrame (ct2) is like below:

| Category | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-06-01 | 123 |
| B | 2022-06-02 | 56 |
| C | 2022-06-03 | 42 |
| C | 2022-06-01 | 84 |
| A | 2022-06-05 | 32 |

My sliders are working, and my dropdown shows items, but when I select a Category, it does not update the chart.

I am facing two issues:

1. My dropdown is not working (When I select a category from dropdown, the chart becomes empty)
2. **I would like to select multiple items from the checkbox instead of selecting just 1 item from a dropdown**

My Code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

fig = go.Figure()
for Category, group in ct2.groupby("Category"):
    fig.add_trace(go.Line(x= group["Date"], y= group["Count"], name= Category,
      hovertemplate="Category=%s<br>Date=%%{x}<br>Count=%%{y}<extra></extra>"% Category))
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text = "Category")
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date")
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Count")

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Time series with range slider and selectors"
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=2,
                     label="2m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)

fig.update_layout(fig_tmp.layout)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": ["visible", [t.legendgroup == c for t in fig.data]],
                }
                for c in ct2["Category"].unique()
            ]
        }
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it was not displayed is that all display settings are false. You need to change the condition to true if the condition is met and false otherwise.

The second question is that there are no checkboxes in plotly's custom controls. If you want to select multiple categories, you should add a button with multiple conditions. The code is as follows. `{'label': 'A_C', 'method': '{'label': 'A_C', 'method': 'update','args': ['visible', [True, False, True]]}`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

fig = go.Figure()
for Category, group in ct2.groupby("Category"):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= group["Date"],
                             y= group["Count"],
                             name= Category,
                             hovertemplate="Category=%s<br>Date=%%{x}<br>Count=%%{y}<extra></extra>"% Category,
                             visible=True,
                            ))
    
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text = "Category")
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date")
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Count")

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Time series with range slider and selectors"
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=2,
                     label="2m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)


buttons = [{'args': [{'visible': [True, False, False]}], 'label': 'A', 'method': 'update'},
           {'args': [{'visible': [False, True, False]}], 'label': 'B', 'method': 'update'},
           {'args': [{'visible': [False, False, True]}], 'label': 'C', 'method': 'update'},
           {'args': [{'visible': [True, False, True]}], 'label': 'A_C', 'method': 'update'},
          ]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": buttons
        }
    ],
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried adding the new button for the second part, but it does not seem to work for me. Could you update the code with that code segment?

Comment: Getting the following error - `ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.dict' received for the 'method' property of layout.updatemenu.button
        Received value: {'label': 'A_C', 'method': 'update', 'args': ['visible', [False, False, True]]}

    The 'method' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
      - One of the following enumeration values:
            ['restyle', 'relayout', 'animate', 'update', 'skip']`

Comment: Updated responses with drop-down, multiple choice cases instead of check buttons. Also, there was a mistake in the code presented in the comments, so I updated that as well.